# How to set up Jenkins for build, unit test and system tests

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng, system-testing

I want to set up Jenkins for a decent build chain for a JavaFX application that controls a robotic arm and other hardware:

- We are using BitBucket with the Git Flow model.
- We have 2 development modules and 1 System Test module in IntelliJ that we build with Maven.
- We have Unit tests, Integration test and System tests. Unit and Integration tests use JUnit and can run on the Jenkins master, for the System tests we use TestNG and they can run the TestFX tests on a Jenkins agent.
  (I think TestNG is more suited for System tests than JUnit)

Development build project (build, unit+integration tests) was already in place. The Test chain has been recently set up by copying the development project, adding the system tests and ignoring the Unit/Integration tests. (so building the application is done twice)

We have 2 types of System tests:

1. Tests that are fairly simple and run on the application itself
2. Tests that are more complex and run on the application that interacts with several simulators for the robotic arm

Now I need to set up the 2nd type of tests.
My question would be: what is the best way to set this up in Jenkins?

I'm reading about Jenkins Pipelines and the Blue Ocean plugin [here](https://dev.to/jalogut/setup-continuos-integrationdelivery-system-in-just-4-steps-with-jenkins-pipelines-and-blue-ocean), about a matrix configuration project [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project). To me it is all a bit confusing what is the ideal way to achieve my goals.

I have no clue how to scale from a testng.xml file in my SystemTest module to flexible tests.
Can I put a sort of capabilities tag to tests so that the correct preconditions are set?  For example, for tests in category 1, only the main application needs to be started for TestFX. However, for tests in the category 2, several simulators needs to be started and configured. I think using a sort of capabilities tag, will make this much more maintainable.

My goals:

- Easy to maintain Jenkins flow
- Efficient building, so preference to copying artifacts instead of building a second time
- Possibility to split the system tests over multiple agents, preferably without me having to be concerned about what runs where (similar to Selenium Grid)
- Correct dependencies (simulators etc) are started depending if the test needs them
- We are looking into running the tests on VMs with OpenGL 3D acceleration due to a canvas used in the application. If tests are able to allocate, start, stop VMs on demand, that would be cool (but would only save some electricity)
- Easy reporting where all test results are gathered from all agents.  Notice that I prefer the JUnit report that highlights which tests were @Ignored. TestNg report format, doesn't say anything about @Ignored tests.